# How to display differents images, not created when the activity is create [ANDROID]

Tags: android, image, android-activity, mobile, wave

I'm developing a game, and in the model of the application I have an 'endless' mode. A number of monsters are created, and when they die new ones are created. The monsters move and they are not always at the same place.

I would like to know how to display them: in the activity, there will be five monsters, but after that there are 4, 3, 2, 1 and 0. I would like to display them dynamically.

Comment: Libgidx and AndEngin might be place to start, as your monster is a sprite in gaming language

Comment: You need to show code you've tried, and where in that code you're getting unexpected behavior. As it stands this is a good description of what you're trying to achieve, but we don't know where you are in the process. Refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

It is good practice to start with already developed game engines if you want to develop games on Android. But its not essential. You can still develop simple games with raw Android.

To do so, you need to have a clear concept on how view and related APIs works.
I will recommend you to explore http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

In your case,

```
Game game = new Game(Game.Settings);
game.createHero();
game.createMonsters();

while(game.playing()){
    game.render();
    if(game.needNewMonster()){
        game.createMonster(); // at random position in view
    }
}
```

Inside `Game.java`,

```
List<Monster> list = new ArrayList<Monster>();
void createMonster(){
    list.add(new Monster("monsterA", x, y, R.drawable.monster)); // x,y are position and monster is drawable for monster. write the model code yourself
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I know how it works but I just don't know how can I resolve this problem :(

Raw it's ok but if in the level there are 2 monsters, I just need 2 imageview for exemple. After if there are 3, i will need 3 imageview so how to do that ?

Comment: See the edited answer. This is just an overview. you should explore more. its tough here to describe more. There are plenty of example in internet. Explore some github raw games...

Comment: Alright, because your example code is what I already have. I just want to display them for the people who plays